# Customizing backbone models to work with urls like /documents/6/editor

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to override the url method of a backbone model to insert the id in the middle of the url string.

**I.e. I dont want to fetch from this**

```
documents/6
```

but this

```
documents/6/editor
```

and similiary update to

```
documents/6/editor
```

Currently backbone insists on always appending the id to the end of the url string.

I tried

```
urlRoot: function(){
  return "/documents" + this.id + "/editor";
}
```

Whilst this works for fetching a model from the server it fails on updates. It seems to be trying the url

```
/documents/6/editor/6
```

and not

```
/documents/6/editor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding [`Model.urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) alters the prefix of your url and is later used in [`Model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url)

Try

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/documents',
    url: function() {
        var base = Backbone.Model.prototype.url.call(this);
        if (this.isNew()) return base;
        return base+'/editor';
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pjr81pLd/

Comment: That's perfect! Didn't think about using the prototype like that.